# ExtJS 5 - Keep scroll position of grid when datastore reloads

Tags: extjs, scroll, refresh

Can anyone tell me how I can keep the position of my scroll bar when my datastore reloads? Below is the code I have for the window/grid and refresh code. Everytime refreshActions executes the scroll bar scrolls to the top of the grid:

preserveScrollonRefresh **does not work in this scenario**

**View**

```
Ext.define('Tool.view.ActionView',{
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
xtype: 'toolactions',
requires:[
    'Tool.view.ActionController'
    ],
controller: 'actions',
viewModel: {},
layout: { type: 'border' },
closeAction: 'hide',
title: 'Actions',
store: 'Task',
width: 1500,
height: 800,    
items: [{
                id: 'ChangeLog',
                xtype: 'grid',
                selType: 'rowmodel',
                split: true,
                title: 'Log',
                region: 'south',
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                bind: {store: '{tasks}'},
                columns: {
                    defaults: {
                    width: 175
                    },
                    items: [
                            { text: 'Script Command', dataIndex: 'command_script', flex: 1},
                            { text: 'Output', dataIndex: 'command_output', width: 250, flex: 1 },
                            { text: 'Status', dataIndex: 'state', width: 250, flex: 1 }]
                    },

            bbar: ['->',{
                           xtype: 'button',
                           text: 'Refresh',
                           listeners: {
                               click: 'refreshActions'
                           }
                    }
            ]

            }]
```

**Refresh Code**

```
refreshActions: function() {
    var me = this;
    this.currentRecord.tasks().load(function(records, operation, success) {
        if(!operation.wasSuccessful()) {
            var message = "Failed to load data from server.";

            if(operation.hasException())
                message = message + " " + operation.getError();

            var app = Tool.getApplication();
            app.toast(message,'error');
        }
        else { 
            me.configureButtons();
            me.configureAutoRefresh();
        }
    });
}
```

**Detect for Auto Refresh**

```
configureAutoRefresh: function() {
    var autoRefresh = false;
    var maxId = this.getMaximumId(this.currentRecord.tasks());
    var maxRecord = this.currentRecord.tasks().getById(maxId);

    if(maxRecord.data.state=='1' || maxRecord.data.state=='0') {
        autoRefresh = true;
    }

    if(autoRefresh == true) {
        if(this.autoRefreshTask == null) {
            var me = this;
            var task = 
                    {
                        run: function() {
                            me.refreshActions();
                            return true;
                        },
                        interval: 2000 // 2 seconds
                    };
            this.autoRefreshTask = Ext.TaskManager.start(task);
        }
    }
    else if(this.autoRefreshTask != null) {
        Ext.TaskManager.stop(this.autoRefreshTask);
        this.autoRefreshTask = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `preserveScrollOnReload`?

Comment: I have tried to put preserveScrollonReload and preserveScrollonRefresh in the viewConfig of the grid with no success.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you have 2 options that not necessarily exclude each other:

1. If a grid row is selected:

   Before the store reload get the selected record using `getSelection()` method and after the action is complete use the `ensureVisible( record, [options] )` method to scroll that record into view.
2. If no row is selected:

   Before the store reload get the current scroll position (I assume in your case is X) using the `getScrollX()` method and after the action is complete use `setScrollX(x, [animate])` to get back to the previous scroll position.